# What is the 'Python' way of creating class attributes

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python. I would like to know which is the better way of creating attributes...

In the first method I am explicitly defining the attribute and then having a method return a value to it:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.a = self._meth( number)

    def _meth(self, num):
        #some executable code here

        return 8 ** num
```

In the second variant the method is being called by itself and is creating the attribute by it self.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self._meth(num)

    def _meth(self, num)
        #some executable code here
        self.a = 8 ** num
```

So my question is which one is the more accepted way of going about this?

this is the code I want to use this for...

```
class Initializer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ParseArguments()
        self.InitializeLogger()

    # Parse command line arguments and display help text    
    def ParseArguments(self):
        help = textwrap.dedent('''\ Help text here''')
        Arguments = argparse.ArgumentParser('This Script Pulls NAV data from the '
                            'AMFI website', 
                            formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, 
                            description=help)
        Arguments.add_argument('-f', '--file',
                               help= 'location of the config')
        self.ArgumentDict = vars(Arguments.parse_args())
        self.ArgumentParser = Arguments




    def CreateLogFile(self, level, name,):
        path = self.ArgumentDict['loc']
        if path == None:
            if platform.system() == 'Windows':
                location = os.environ.get("TEMP") + '\\' + name
            elif platform.system == 'Linux':
                location = os.getenv("HOME") + '/' + name
            else:
                print "Unsupported OS"
                raise ValueError
        else:
            location = path
        formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - "
                                      "%(levelname)s - %(message)s")
        logfile = logging.FileHandler(location)
        logfile.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logfile.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(logfile)


    def InitializeLogger(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('main')
        if self.ArgumentDict['debug'] == True:
            self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        else:
            self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.CreateLogFile(logging.INFO, 'NavUpdaterLog.log'))
```

Comment: `return None` can be shortened to `return`, and if it only occurs at the end of the function/method, you can (and should) omit it. If you don't return a value, or don't return at all but get to the end of the function/method, its return value is `None`.

Comment: My answer is that it's impossible to say without knowing what you're actually doing. Can you provide more information about the use case, preferably including code?  (Also note: for Python 2, use `class X(object):`, new-style classes)

Comment: I will add more information, and have made the changes as previously suggested..

Comment: @Jodgod Why is it **met** in ``__init_()`` and **_met** in ``def _meth()`` ? I wonder if I'm ignoring something in Python or if it is a typo error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you're creating object attributes, not class attributes (Those go directly in the class body). If `meth` is only called on initialization, I'd prefer:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__():
         # Some executable code here
         self.a = 8
```

Otherwise, if your class can't handle `meth` being called every now and then, you should make it a private method by prefixing it with `_` or `__`.

By the way `return None` (with a capitalized **N**one) at the end of a method is unnecessary, that's the default final instruction anyway.

Looking at the updated code, I can't find any need to use classes in the first place. You may want to have a helper method `initLogger`, but that's it. Try to:

- Use builtin-in functionality instead of reimplementing it yourself, for example [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mktemp)
- Roughly follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in your style (i.e. don't capitalize method and variable names)

Answer (score 0):

In your second definition, you can only use the method to set the instance variable `a`. In your first, you can use the method again if you need it. Also, I don't like looking all over the place for instance variables, so I would go with number one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct python way would be to do it the easiest way, removing all unnecessary code.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 8
```

If you need to define custom getter and setters, you can use [python properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property). This in an extract from python documentation :

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that it depends. If there is only one attribute, like in your example, then the whole body of `meth` can go into the `__init__` method. If you have say 5-10 attributes to initialize, `__init__` would get to long and I would definitely try to refactor the initialization code into functions. If the initialization of each attribute is independent of the other, I would first try to use functions.

```
def get_attr_a():
    # some code
    return a
def get_attr_b():
    ...
    return b
...
class A:
    def __init__():
        self.a = get_attr_a()
        self.b = get_attr_b()
        ...
```

If the initialization of attributes are dependent on each other, so that b can not be initialized before a is done, then it is a trickier case. That could warrant some kind of factory pattern where the initialization of the object is detached from the class:

```
class A:
    def__init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c

def get_attr_a():
    return a
def get_attr_b(a):
    return b
def create_an_a_class():
    a = get_attr_a()
    b = get_attr_b(a)
    c = get_attr_c(a, b)
    ....
    return A(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

using init is an understandable way (for other programmer) of creating attribute.

Usually __ init __  is thy way I start my reading of the python class and scan through the methods.